# SQL command to insert values into related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've 2 tables in my database **GROUP** : id_group, name_group. And **RHIGHT**: id_right, name_right. A group can have one or n rights, same thing for the right, can be in one or n groups. Between these two tables, i've a table containing id_group, id_right, date_right. I need an **INSERT** statement to insert(at the same time) a GROUP with its RIGHTS and also the DATE. And listing later all groups each one with its all rights and dates with a SELECT statement.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for.  An insert statement?  A select?  Could you edit the question to provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yes an insert statement to insert data into the tables i've mentioned bellow at the same time. I want to insert a group with its rights and also the date.

Comment: Look up `transaction` in MySQL documentation or Google "MySQL transaction".  This allows you to do multiple data manipulation operations that all take effect at the same time.

Comment: There are only some 226 reserved words in MySQL. You managed to pick two of them. Seriously unlucky.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to insert into multiple tables *at the same time* however it is possible to do them all in one transaction.

Usually in your case i'd insert into Group if the current group doesn't exist, insert into thight if rhight doesn't exist and then insert into your joining table either the new ID of group and rhight or just the current returned ID's for them.

Regards
Liam

Comment: Just to complete the picture: there *are* databases where you can insert into several tables in a single statement - just not in MySQL

Comment: Thank u guys for ur answers. My problem is the date in the join table. To insert a date, i should have already groups and rights in my database. If I want, for example, to insert new date this is not possible, i should first insert a group. And this is not what i want. I want to insert a new group with its rights and a date in each right.